# How Can I pass arguments into paint() for drawing ovals?

Tags: java, methods, graphics, draw, paint

I want to pass two integer values from another method to paint(Graphics g, int a, int b)

```
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    
        g.drawLine(10, 330, 410, 330);
            g.drawLine(40, 30, 40, 360);
        
            for(int u=0;u<z;u++) {    
            g.drawOval(33, u+10, 20, 20);
            
        }
            
        }
```

But when I try to pass the values it does not display anything in the frame.

**How can I pass two integer values in order to draw ovals according to that numbers or I can not override the paint method?**

Some tips would be helpful.

Comment: Simple and short answer: You have to store whatever you need for painting. In this case, store `z` as a field in the class (but give it a proper name!), and just call `repaint()` so that the `paint` method can use it: There is **much** more to say, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html and many questions here on stackoverflow.

Comment: And you've *already* been given this link days ago which begs the question -- why haven't you read it yet? Of if you've read it, why are you not following its advice?

Answer (score -1):

What makes it possible to draw on the right canvas is the Graphics variable that you have in the draw void, you would not be able to just add your own variables to the draw void, but you could make a new one which inherits the graphics g variable from the draw void and gets the integers from calling it. Maybe not ideal but it would work.

For example you could make a public graphics element on the top of the class and inside the draw void do this:

```
publicGraphics = g;
```

Then inside your new void you could make it like this:

```
public void drawCustom(int x, int y){
    publicGraphics.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

Or of course you could just make the variables you want to pass forward public instead of passing them on when calling the void, but that only works for some cases of course.

Hope this helps

EDIT:

This worked perfectly for me:

```
    public Graphics publicGraphics;
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
     g.drawLine(10, 330, 410, 330); 
     g.drawLine(40, 30, 40, 360); 
     publicGraphics = g; 
     } 
 public void drawCustom(int p, int o, int z) { 
     for (int u = 0; u < z; u++) { 
         publicGraphics.drawOval(p, o, 50, 50); 
         } 
     }
```

Then you could just do `drawCustom(50, 50, 70);`

I didn't understand why you do the for loop or why you tried to do it in the paint void and custom draw void as well?

Comment: A Graphics object is only valid for a single call to a paint method, unless you created it yourself.  Storing it in a field is a bad idea.

Comment: static Graphics publicGraphics;
 public void paint(Graphics g) {

  g.drawLine(10, 330, 410, 330);
  g.drawLine(40, 30, 40, 360);
  publicGraphics = g;
  for (int u = 0; u < z; u++) {
   g.drawOval(33, u + 10, 20, 20);

  }
 }

 public static void drawCustom(int p, int o) {
  for (int u = 0; u < z; u++) {

   publicGraphics.drawOval(p, o, 50, 50);

  }
 } I tried what you said like that but it still gives null pointer because of publicGraphics.drawOval however it can take o and successfully in drawCustom method.   @VGR Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what you just sent me made no sense at all when i pasted it into my IDE. Where do you create the z variable?

Comment: This is very bad advice. That `publicGraphics` variable will not hold a stable Graphics object which risks disappearing images or worse, a NullPointerException.

Comment: Well, do you have a solution that is better? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Yes, to do Graphics as per the [Swing Graphics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)'s recommendations, to use a Graphics object that has been passed into a paintComponent method, to not store this object into a field but to only use it within this method (or methods called within paintComponent.